# How to prevent that rowSelector's clickAction method is fired when using any button on the page?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, icefaces

I have a `ice:dataTable` with a `ice:rowSelector` in one column, and a `ice:selectBooleanCheckbox` in another column. The `ice:rowSelector` has `toggleOnInput` set to false.
If I select a checkbox (with a click) in one row, the clickAction is not fired (because of `toggleOnInput` - so far, so good).
But If I click on a button on the same page after this, regardless of what action bindings they have, the rowSelector's `clickAction` is fired. Why?
Any ideas to prevent this?

Here is my page definition:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <f:view>
        <ice:form>
            <ice:commandButton value="Test" />

            <ice:dataTable id="dataTable"
                       value="#{PageBean.data}"
                       var="entity">
                <ice:column>
                    <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox />
                </ice:column>
                <ice:column>
                    <ice:outputText value="#{entity.name}" />
                    <ice:rowSelector clickAction="#{PageBean.clickAction}" toggleOnInput="false" />                 
                </ice:column>
            </ice:dataTable>
       </ice:form>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: If you remove the clickAction of your rowSelector, is it still fired?

Comment: No, if I remove it, it isn't fired.

Comment: what are you doing in the `PageBean#clickAction` method?

Comment: I do something related to the table row that is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making different forms for other buttons in the page and the data table, we should not have nested forms but can have multiple forms

Also I would suggest to use `selectionAction` attribute if you are performing an Action method to call when the respective row is clicked.

Hope this could help you

Comment: Solved it by using `selectionAction` as you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using a command button which is specified as:

```
ice:commandButton

The ice:commandButton tag displays a button which can be linked to an action in 
a backing bean method by specifying the bean and the method in the actionListener
attribute. The button can be replaced by an image by specifying the URL of the  
image in the image attribute.
```

Where I clearly see that it's backed by a bean method. Check your code thoroughly.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your effort, but I don't understand what you want to say. As you see in my question, my button isn't linked to a backing bean method. It's the rowSelectors clickAction that is fired.

Comment: I think this is a bug in ice-faces, you need to manipulate something from the server side on the bean value so that whenever the button is pressed never do anything related to the row selector.